# Vector of Vector Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segmentation fault when I try to assign values to this vector of vectors. I'm basically reading in pixels from an image and then trying to create a vector of vectors with you being able to access the row and then the pixel on that row to get the pixels in that spot. But when I try to assign the specific pixel to a pixel value it gives me a segmentation fault. I am using a placeholder of {255,255,255} as an example pixel but I plan to use this->PIX[num_pix].r() if i can get it to work which is basically the pixel getter inside my Image class with num_pix being the current pixel that it's iterated on.

```
vector<vector<Pixel>> Image::as_rows(){
  vector<vector<Pixel>> pixels;
  int i,k,height, width,pix_num;
  pix_num=0;
  height = this->HDR.height();
  width = this->HDR.width();
  for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(k=0;k<width;k++){
       pix_num++;
       pixels[i][k] = {255,255,255};
    }
  }
  return pixels;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to resize your vectors beforehand. Accessing a vector's elements does not automatically resize it to ensure that element exists. That, or push_back the elements and vectors as they become available.

Comment: You have to `push_back` or [construct](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) at the right size, you can't just start smashing data into an empty vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector is currently empty, which means you'll have undefined behavior when you try to assign to memory you don't own (with `pixels[i][k] = {255, 255, 255}`).

You can initialize your vector with the correct amount of objects when you declare it:

```
vector<vector<Pixel>> pixels(height, vector<Pixel>(width));
```

Also, for the future, you can use `.at()` instead of the subscript operator to enforce bounds checking and avoid UB.

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty vector that you're trying to access, which is undefined behavior.  You have to allocate the elements before you can access them by index like you're trying to do. An alternative to initializing your vector with the correct amount of objects at the start is to `push_back` the objects as you need them.  With your vector of vector of `Pixel` objects you'll want something like this to populate.

```
std::vector<std::vector <Pixel> > pixels;
for(i=0;i<height;i++)
{
    pixels.push_back(std::vector<Pixel>());
    for(k=0;k<width;k++)
    {
        pix_num++;
        pixels[i].push_back({255,255,255});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `pixels` is an empty vector.  It's elements are `vector<Pixel>` - but it hasn't got any elements.  The cheap and cheerful solution is to calculate `height` and `width` first, and then construct `pixels` with enough elements of the right size:

```
    const int height = this->HDR.height();
    const int width  = this->HDR.width();
    std::vector<std::vector<Pixel>> pixels(height, {width, {0,0,0}});
```

However, this will have horribly memory locality properties.  I strongly recommend you write a `Bitmap` class which maps an x,y to an offset in a single vector, and which you construct with a width and height.